# how to calculate distance between two different shapes numpy array in order to do KNN implementation

Tags: python, numpy

1.Now I had two Numpy array which shape size are training set (21000,784) and test set(2000,784) respectively. Is this  possible to do calculation?

```
test_lable = label_test

((data_train_set - data_partial_test)**2).sum(axis=1)
print(data_partial_test.shape)
print(data_train_set.shape)
```

Comment: I tried, which said operands could not be broadcast ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the subtraction is performed along the first axis by default. And since the arrays differ in number of rows, it returns an error:

```
train = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
test = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

((train - test)**2).sum(axis=1)
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (3,3)
```

To subtract along the first axis, you can add another axis to `test`:

```
((train - test[:,None])**2).sum(axis=1)
array([[ 9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [45, 45, 45]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` for this.

As an alternative, you can use reshaping:

```
a = np.random.rand(21000, 784).reshape([1, 21000, 784])
b = np.random.rand(2000, 784).reshape([2000, 1, 784])

np.sum((a-b)**2, axis=-1)
```